# create counter for blog categories in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-5.8

I´m traying to create one counter for my blog´s categories. This should appear to the right name side of my category . i´m using my model with variable appends, that after i will use in my blade for show my result in one span. But i don´t know very well how i can use count in my Model. I´m doing this in my model Blog.

my variable appends contain:

```
protected $appends = [
        'custom_fields',
        'has_media',
        'restaurant',
        'blog_category',
        'viewer',
        'postCounter',
    ];
```

i´m traying this:

```
return $this->blogs()->count();
```

i have a relation between blog and blog_category with:

```
public function blogCategory()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\BlogCategory::class, 'blog_category_id', 'id');
    }
```

i want to do in my view appear for example:

```
innovation   (2)
```

in my view i´m doing this:

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
     <li><a href="{{ url('blogs/'.$category->name) }}">{{ trans('web.blog_category_'.$category->name) }}</a><span>{{$category->postCounter}}</span></li>
@endforeach
```

but always returned me 0, and i have post with categories

**updated**

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `->post_counter`? If your method is named `getPostCounterAttribute` the attribute is `post_counter` as stated in [Defining An Accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor)

Comment: yes, i can access for` ->post_counter` or for my append variable but i need that if other categories haven´t got any post counter appear 0. Always appear 1. I´m have other post in other categories. i updated my question with capture from y db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [laravel relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) `withCount` you can do this easily. If you want to count the number of results from a relationship without actually loading them you may use the withCount method, which will place a `{relation}_count` column on your resulting models.

add `withCount` method to your query

```php
$categories = Category::withCount('blogCategory')->get();
```

You can access the count in your foreach loop

```php
// $category->blogCategory_count
@foreach($categories as $category)
   <li>
      <a href="{{ url('blogs/'.$category->name) }}"> 
         {{trans('web.blog_category_'.$category->name) }}
      </a>
      <span>{{$category->blogCategory_count}}</span> 
   </li>
@endforeach
```